# Cannot set property type of #<HTMLTextAreaElement>

Tags: jquery

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property type of # which has only a getter

Code:

```
const [node] = $('input[name="train_description"]');
const attrs = {};
$.each(node.attributes, (index, attribute) => {
  attrs[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
});
console.log(attrs)
$(this).replaceWith($('<textarea>').prop(attrs));
```

Sorry, been out of programming for the past decade and was asked to look into this. Pulling a form from a database and need to change a text input into a textarea so it can be modified easier.

Any suggestions on the above error I am getting?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, instead of `prop` try using `attr` i.e : `$(this).replaceWith($('<textarea>').attr(attrs));` see if that works .

Comment: Some DOM properties are read-only. This means you're trying to set one of them.

Comment: What does `console.log(attrs)` show?